# fitting linear model on very large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I dataframe with around 2 million records in it.  I've provided a sample of the data below.  I'm trying to fit a linear model to it, I've provided the code below.  The issue I'm running in to is that it's taking forever.  Does anyone have any tips that could speed it up?  Even sampling just 20K records and trying to fit a model takes forever on my machine.  My end goal is to try to see if there's any correlation between the categorical variables and the loan_amount.  So I'm fitting a linear model and running anova.  If anyone has an alternative suggestion that works better with large data, I'm all ears as well.

```
Code:

import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

sample_df['buyer']=sample_df['buyer'].astype('category')
sample_df['seller']=sample_df['seller'].astype('category')
sample_df['property_type']=sample_df['property_type'].astype('category')
sample_df['lender']=sample_df['lender'].astype('category')
sample_df['year_built']=sample_df['year_built'].astype('category')


mod = ols('loan_amount~buyer',
                data=sample_df).fit()
```

data:

```
print sample_df.iloc[1:10]

                id                             property_address  \
1452006   577982716      10407 HILLGATE AVE BAKERSFIELD CA 93311   
1368833   579792639       717 SANTA ISABEL DR SAN DIEGO CA 92114   
1276131   577296028                                          NaN   
3095127   585549018   2300 GREENBRIAR DR #C CHULA VISTA CA 91915   
1032186   574454847                                          NaN   
12094387  570361895         1253 CHAMBERLIN CT CAMPBELL CA 95008   
8622975   567312492  9424 TWIN TRAILS DR #204 SAN DIEGO CA 92129   
1214389   577538408       651 ASPEN MEADOWS WAY LINCOLN CA 95648   
3155561   587054191     950 SHORE POINT CT #206 ALAMEDA CA 94501   

                                      buyer                     seller  \
1452006     BLAYLOCK,ANDREW L|WINTON,SARA A       LENNAR HMS OF CA INC   
1368833   VELAZQUEZ,VICTOR A|ODOM,SHANDEL G                        NaN   
1276131                  ASTON HOLDINGS LLC                MOTE,JOHN C   
3095127              KEOUGH,JOSEPH & SANDRA              KEOUGH,JOSEPH   
1032186           HOMEQUEST INVESTMENTS INC  ANDERSEN MONICA & K TRUST   
12094387       HALLOCK,KAREN A LIVING TRUST            HALLOCK,KAREN A   
8622975        MATAAFA,VALE P & CHRISTINE L                        NaN   
1214389               MONROE,COBY & DESIRAE                        NaN   
3155561                  JACOBSEN,JESSICA L          WONG JENNIE TRUST   

         transaction_date  property_id property_type  transaction_amount  \
1452006        2016-08-08    182232030          RSFR              281000   
1368833        2016-09-27     26293661          RSFR                   0   
1276131        2016-07-06     30827189          VRES                   0   
3095127        2016-12-16     26352345          RCON                   0   
1032186        2016-06-23     29966416          RSFR              300000   
12094387       2016-04-06    104705632          RSFR                   0   
8622975        2016-03-15     25941782          RCON                   0   
1214389        2016-08-18     97638435          RSFR                   0   
3155561        2016-12-16     38308490          RCON              370000   

          loan_amount                     lender  sqft  year_built  trans_yr  
1452006        275664  UNIVERSAL AMERICAN MTG CO  2105           0      2016  
1368833        285000               EQUIFUND MTG  1115        1950      2016  
1276131        450000     AMERICAN AGCREDIT FLCA     0           0      2016  
3095127        225000     FINANCE OF AMERICA MTG  1600        1996      2016  
1032186             0                        NaN   780        1929      2016  
12094387            0                        NaN  3544        2004      2016  
8622975        326947               PLAZA HM MTG  1127        1986      2016  
1214389        356000     FINANCE OF AMERICA MTG  3023        2002      2016  
3155561        333000                       USAA   770        1972      2016
```

Comment: Time model creation an fit separately. Two million observation is not big on modern machines. However, how many unique buyers do you have? Creating a huge dense array of dummy variables might be slow.

Comment: @user333700 Thank you for getting back to me.  I've already run the fit part separately, and yes it is the part that is taking forever.  I've also got around 1.7 million unique buyers.  Is that just way too many to work with?

Comment: If you have 1.7 million users and only 2 million observations then it's likely that for many users you don't have enough observations to estimate a categorical fixed effect. Current OLS in statsmodels is not designed for that many explanatory variables. I worked for a while on PRs for absorbing fixed effects, e.g. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2568. Additionally the linearmodels package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/linearmodels should have some methods for this, although I never tried it out.

Comment: @user333700  Thank you very much, I think you've pretty much answered my question.